# Is it possible to reset and re-number cross references to figures in quarto / R

Tags: r, quarto

### The challenge

In an R quarto markdown document: Correctly count 20 figures in the main manuscript by order of reference **and** do so separately (arabic 1:20) from two figures in supplementary materials (Alpha A:B)

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions/3943).

Answer (score 0):

### My dirty hack

I offer a dirty hack solution to my own question, which is based on hijacking the *theorem* cross reference scheme:

```
---
title: "Figure cross-reference resetting"
subtitle: "A dirty hack"
format: html
crossref:
  thm-title:  Supplementary figure
  thm-prefix: Supplementary figure
  thm-labels: alpha A
---

## A manuscript

See @fig-elephant

See @thm-supplementary-elephant in the supplementary materials.

## Figures

![An elephant](elephant.png){#fig-elephant}

## Supplementary materials

::: {#thm-supplementary-elephant}
![The same elephant but now as supplementary material](elephant.png)
:::
```

### Short comings

- The theorem scheme is sacrificed -- i.e. not available for theorems if need be.
- No caption for the theorem(?)